# How to prevent textarea from dancing while typing and running into page bottom? : JQuery/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am continuously typing into auto sizing textarea;

When text goes runs into bottom of page and i continue typing;

What i find is that the page dancing like hell on each keypress or keyup and text runs into bottom of page (for which i need to scroll down to check what is happening). How to prevent page dancing and text running into bottom?

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/osbnnbxa/

Browser: IE10 (Also find little dancing in firefox; but client use IE10 so need to work on that only)

HTML:

```
<div>
 <div>
  <br><br> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <textarea class="normal" name="myarea" id="myarea" style="height: 100px; overflow-y: hidden;"></textarea>
  </div>
</div> 
<input type="button" class="butt" value="ehehehhe" />
```

JQuery:

```
var myquery = {
  autoHeight: function(e) {
  $(e).css({
  'height': 'auto',
  'overflow-y': 'hidden'
 }).height(e.scrollHeight);
},
init: function() {
setTimeout(function() {
  $('textarea').each(function() {
    myquery.autoHeight(this);
  }).on('input', function() {
    myquery.autoHeight(this);
  });
}, 200);
$("textarea").keypress(function(e) {
   $(".butt").focus();    
   $(this).focus();    
});
  }

};

$(myquery.init);
```

**Update**: Customer says do not define maximum height of textarea. Let it flow as the text increases.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am not on IE10 but check once by giving `box-sizing: border-box` to the textarea.

Comment: @Mr_Green: May be same happen in other browser version if you could run fiddle?

Comment: @RRR: What i am trying to achieve is to enter text without fluttering whole page.

Comment: yea i got that... sorry i meant to ask what are you trying to achieve with that jQuery script?

Comment: @fatherazrael Are you just trying to keep the `<textarea>` from growing too high? You could do something simple in the `CSS` like this:

    textarea {
      max-height: 10em;
    }

Comment: @AndrewHoffman: Customer says not to add max height to textarea. Let it flow like hell :(

Comment: @RRR: Script includes AUTOSIZE and Keyup function include focussing so that control jumps to textarea cursor (which runs to bottom of page)

Comment: @Mr_Green: Box-sizing:border-box is not working :'(

Comment: i am sorry but i find your script confusing.... say like you have mentioned `'height': 'auto',
  'overflow-y': 'hidden'`  it doesnt make sense coz when the height is auto(and not fixed) there is no question of overflow-y

Comment: `$("textarea").keypress(function(e) {
   $(".butt").focus();    
   $(this).focus();    
});`  you are tyring to focus button then shifting the focus back to textarea... why is that? I am sorry if i am bugging you

Comment: @RRR: Thanks. I have removed focussing statement. But error does not get resolved.

Comment: page flickers coz you are using `setTimeout` and you are shifting the focus to button and then back to textarea so scroll happens and it appears  as if page flickered :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109498/discussion-between-fatherazrael-and-rrr).

Comment: @fatherazrael I created a different approach. don't know how this works. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/osbnnbxa/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I know you said to let the textarea flow, but I really like this solution. In your fiddle, it lets the textarea grow to close to the bottom of the viewport and stops all the dancing. It's hopefully a reasonable compromise. Modified fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/osbnnbxa/12/).

```
textarea {
  max-height: 85vh;
}
```